# Why don't I see files after push to Bare git repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have my local dev repo (origin) and a remote repo which I created using **git init --bare** as [recommended here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F). I also ran `git --bare update-server-info`

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

Git remote -v shows

```
origin  http://staging.websitename.com (fetch)

origin  http://staging.websitename.com (push)

remote  ssh://user@xx.xx.xx/home/user/public_html/staging (fetch)

remote  ssh://user@xx.xx.xx/home/user/public_html/staging (push)
```

**After this and running git push remote or git push -all remote, it goes through and gives me no errors. Why don't I see the files on the remote repo??**

```
Compressing objects: 100% (4121/4121), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4242/4242), 18.70 MiB | 694 KiB/s, done.
Total 4242 (delta 495), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: I found this answer **extremely helpful**; it allows you to do what you want with very minimal steps: https://superuser.com/questions/1316300/how-to-sync-a-local-dir-to-server-using-git

Answer (score 8):

Bare repositories don't have working copies so you won't "see" any files. Try doing a git log, you can see the commits. Clone from the bare repo and you'll get files.

Comment: Thanks, I thought bare repos were the ideal repos that will only be PUSHED to so I was going to use this as a staging server (so of course will need to see the files. Should I CLONE the local repo instead even though I don't need full git tree?

Comment: @KevinOrin: You should have your running stage version separate from the bare repository since pushing to a non-bare repository has a number of issues. You can update it with a `git pull` run from a post-update hook in the bare repository.

Comment: Thanks but don't think I will need a Bare repo at all @BenjaminBannier - I am just wondering how to setup the staging since a simple "git init" in the past has led to a tree issue when I tried to push to it.

Comment: A bare repository contains only your history. A normal repository contains your history and a copy of whichever branch you have checked out. The reason you should have a bare repository is that a normal one has to be checked out somewhere, and you can not push to a checked out branch (git would not know what to do with any conflicts).

Answer (score 5):

The essential point of a `--bare` repo is that it does not have a working copy (nor an index), which means there is nothing to get messed-up by a push.

If you want certain pushes (to one or more particular branches) to "auto-deploy", the way to make that happen is to use a git hook in the `--bare` repo.  The hook—generally `post-receive`, although it's possible to use the `pre-receive` or `update` hooks here—is run on *all* pushes, so it should check whether the push in question is "interesting" (affects the auto-deploy branch(es)), and if so, trigger the deployment.

The hook is run on behalf of the process doing the push (often ssh as some user, as in your `git remote -v` output), so if the deployed files should be owned by another user, you must arrange that somehow.  One easy, simple, and reasonable method is to write to file that is set to mode `rw-rw-rw-` (write-able by everyone), and have something (such as a cron job) check the file periodically.  If written, the cron job—running as the deployment user—can extract the latest version of the appropriate branch(es).  Another method is to contact a server (puppet, etc) that does this.

If the user doing the push (`user@xx.xx.xx`) can own the files, an even simpler method is to run `git checkout` in the hook, but [with an alternate work-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076744/1256452) that has no other connection with the `--bare` repo.