# GIT clone changes to Windows directory

Tags: git

When I use `git status` I have the following lines:

```
modified:   system/controllers/accounts.php
modified:   system/models/account.php
```

How can I copy these changes to a windows directory without changing the git status?

So my windows tree would be:

- system/

  - controllers/

    - accounts.php
  - models/

    - account.php

Comment: These files should be in subdirectories. Forward slashes work fine almost anywhere (which means everywhere except the cmd utilities).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [the other question you just deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459729/git-copy-all-changes-to-windows-directory). You are looking for a deployment process, and the linked question there answers how to do that.

Comment: @poke my answer is totaly different from [the duplicate you pointed me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269426/git-post-receive-hook-to-checkout-each-branch-to-different-folders). Please, don't just close questions without being sure its a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with (with the help of Stony) and [this source](http://tosbourn.com/using-git-to-create-an-archive-of-changed-files/):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

# Navigate to the directory
cd .
cd D://NetBeansProjects/project/

# Check status, what files are changed?
git status

# Ask for commit message
read -p "Commit message: " message

# Add the changes to the head
git add .

# Commit the changes
git commit -m "$message"

# Archive the last changed files
git archive -o ~/Desktop/update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)

# Pause the terminal so I have time to read
$SHELL
```

This does change the status, but that is the GIT way I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the context where the files are modified. So you can go to that directory and copy that files to another location or you use the command line and copy them.

So if you copy them in that branch you don't modify them.

To copy all modified files (if you have a lot of files) then you can try the following line.

```
cp -R $(git ls-files --modified) ../modified-foder-for-files
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now, but when changed over 100 files, this costs a lot of time. I'm looking for a way to do that automaticly since GIT does know what files are changed.

Comment: Then you should write that in your question :D i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I am almost there. This command does copy the files, but ignores the directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction! I got is using: `git archive --format=zip HEAD $(git ls-files --modified) > update.zip`, This wil copy the tree structure.