# GIT post-receive multiple branch deployment

Tags: ruby, git

I have a development and production folder on the same server and 1 repo behind them to push to both folders depending on the branch that is pushed. I would like the development folder to be deployed to when develop is pushed to the repo and the production folder when master is pushed. I have an edited ruby post-receive file I found on a different site but I am new to ruby and can't seem to figure out why it isn't pushing to either folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive

from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

if (branch =~ /^master/)

    puts "Received branch #{branch}, deploying to production."

    deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('/var/www/html/production')
    `GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
    puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"

    exit
    ∂
elsif (branch =~ /^develop/)

    puts "Received branch #{branch}, deploying to development."

    deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('/var/www/html/development')
    `GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f develop`
    puts "DEPLOY: develop(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"

    exit

end
```

Any help on this post-receive or a replacement would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that swiggle under the first `exit` supposed to be there? Sorry don't know much about Ruby either!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind shell script instead of Ruby then these people have solved the same problem.

[Git post-receive hook to checkout each branch to different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269426/git-post-receive-hook-to-checkout-each-branch-to-different-folders)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little late to the party on this, however maybe it will help others that are trying to find a solution in Ruby. Here is a working example (modified from [this source](http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git) which got me sorted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 2. Only deploy if staging or master branch was pushed
if (branch =~ /staging$/) == nil && (branch =~ /master$/) == nil
    puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory(Path to deploy is relative to the git bare repo: e.g. website-root/repos)
if (branch =~ /staging$/)
    deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../path-to-staging-deploy.com')
    `GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f staging`
    puts "DEPLOY: staging(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"

elsif (branch =~ /master$/)
    deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../path-to-master-deploy.com')
        `GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
        puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"
else
    puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end
```

I'm new to Ruby so there is probably a better way to write this, but it is working as expected - as far as I can see.