# Git post-receive not working when pushing non master branch to remote

Tags: git, workflow, branch, git-remote

I'm setting up Git and I'm coming up against an issue with my branches.

My intention is to have three versions of my site: one the **local environment**, another the **staging environment** and the final the **production site**.

I've setup a repo on my **local**, which is the **master branch**. I'm successfully able to setup a remote via SSH and push files to the bare repo on the staging server which triggers a post-receive, moving those files to the public_html directory.

The problems arise when I create a **new branch** and push that to a **new remote** directing to the **prod server**. The files are pushed to the bare repo on the prod server however it seems that the post-receive is not firing and not moving the files to the public_html directory.

The post-receive looks like this:

`#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/user/public_html  --git-dir=/home/user/wpstaging.git checkout -f`

My research has fallen short but I believe the reason it's not firing the post-receive hook is something to do with the fact that **I'm no longer on the master branch**.

Am I doing something obviously incorrect here? I am new to Git and setting up a workflow for the first time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19269426/1256452

Answer (score 0):

Are you confident that the hook is not firing, or could it be firing and not doing what you expect?

The post-receive hook responds to the fact that a push occurred.  Only if the hook goes looking explicitly does it depend on *what* was pushed or to *which* branch.

However, the way you're using `checkout` doesn't necessarily check out the commit that was just pushed.  (How would that work, if you pushed multiple branches at once?)  In a default setup it would checkout the `master` branch, because that's what the `HEAD` file points to

You could try moving `HEAD` to the branch you want checked out on that server, or you could modify the hook to explicitly check out the branch you want deployed on that server.  (While both might work, the latter is probably safer.)